# Ansible playbook stuck indefinitely on remotely executing a PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, winrm

I have an issue when trying to remotely execute a PowerShell script with Ansible. The PowerShell script (which works on its own without Ansible) essentially creates a virtual machine and copies a sysprepped VHD which is located in our NAS. It needs 3 arguments from the user (on which server do you want to create the virtual machine in, on which partition should the vhd and vm data be located in and what will be the name of the VM).

This is how the playbook looks like:

```
- hosts: windows_host
  tasks:
   - name: Run remote PowerShell script
     win_shell: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:/Path/To/Script/Script.ps1 {{ server }} {{ partition }} {{ hostname }}
```

This is how I execute the playbook:
ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbook.yml --extra-var "server=server.mydomain.local partition=E: hostname=devtest" -vvvv

The connection gets established, but the playbook never finishes it just stays stuck. Enabling debug and verbose does not give any additional information. This is the last line I get when using debugging:

<windows_host.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: user@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL on PORT 5985 TO windows_host.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
1058240 1669392256.73059: checking if winrm_host windows_host.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL is an IPv6 address
calling kinit with pexpect for principal user@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)

I created a different playbook and PowerShell script (creates a file which name gets assigned by the user)

$name=$args[0]
New-Item -Path "C:\Temp$name.txt"

and I am able to successfully execute the playbook which starts the PowerShell script without error.

Below is my ansible configuration (if needed):

```
user@ansible:/etc/ansible$ ansible -i hosts windows_host -m setup
HOSTNAME.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_architecture": "64-bit",
        "ansible_architecture2": "x86_64",
        "ansible_bios_date": "05/23/2012",
        "ansible_bios_version": "090006",
        "ansible_date_time": {
        [more data]
        "ansible_distribution": "Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Datacenter",
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "10",
        "ansible_distribution_version": "10.0.20348.0",
        "ansible_domain": "MYDOMAIN.LOCAL",
        [[more data]]
        },
        "ansible_fqdn": "HOSTNAME.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL",
        "ansible_hostname": "HOSTNAME",
        "ansible_interfaces": [
            {
                "connection_name": "Ethernet",
                "default_gateway": "192.168.0.254",
                "dns_domain": null,
                "interface_index": 5,
                "interface_name": "Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter",
                "ipv4": {
                    "address": "192.168.0.100",
                    "prefix": "24"
                },
                "ipv6": {},
                "mtu": 1500,
                "speed": 10000
            }
        ],
        "ansible_ip_addresses": [
            "192.168.0.100"
        ],


user@ansible:/etc/ansible$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.10]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 2.10.1
  libyaml = True


user@ansible:/etc/ansible$ sudo nano hosts
[windows_host]
windows_host.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL

[windows_host:vars]
ansible_user=windows_user@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
ansible_password= {{ password }}
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=kerberos
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 60
ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 58
```

Any advice?

EDIT: This is the content of the PowerShell script:

```
$userName="user"
$File="C:\Path\To\User\user.txt"
$hyperv_host=$args[0]
$partition=$args[1]
$host_name=$args[2]
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "$userName", (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)

$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{'Invoke-Command:ConfigurationName'='remote_host' }
$nas_location = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\path\in\NAS\location\VHD\sysprep.vhdx"
Invoke-Command  -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
(New-Item -Verbose "$using:partition\$using:host_name" -type directory)
(Copy-Item -Verbose -Path "$using:nas_location" -Destination "$using:partition\$using:host_name")
(Write-Host "VHD successfully copied from \\NAS\")
(Rename-Item -Verbose -Path "$using:partition\$using:host_name\sysprep.vhdx" -NewName "$using:host_name.vhdx")
(New-VM -Verbose -Name "$using:host_name" -MemoryStartupBytes 16GB -Generation 2  -Path "$using:partition\$using:host_name" -BootDevice VHD -VHDPath "$using:partition\$using:host_name\$using:host_name.vhdx")
(Set-VMProcessor -Verbose "$using:host_name" -Count 4)
    } -ComputerName $hyperv_host
```

And this is how I execute it:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:/Path/To/Script/Script.ps1 hypervhost.mylocal.domain F: dev-vm
```

Comment: The most common cause for shell scripts hanging for ever in ansible is that it is waiting for some user input. Raising verbosity will not help diagnosis as the controller won't get anything from the target until the task is done. Please make sure you're not in that case. If not, an example run of that script manually on your target server would probably help. Automating answering prompts for scripts is possible on linux targets through the [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html). But there's no windows equivalent I know.

Comment: Just for clarification, I am using a PowerShell script, not a shell script. I have tested the script manually and it works.  I basically copied my cmd command for the script trigger from windows and added it to the playbook.

Comment: Just for clarification, PowerShell is a shell as its name suggest (as much as cmd, sh, bash, zsh, tcsh, ash.....). As stated earlier it would probably help to have an example run of your script as well as it's content.

Comment: I have modified the OP to include the script and a sample of how I execute the script.

Comment: My guess is that your script runs flawlessly when your run it locally inside a session on your windows host but asks for a credential/input/confirmation when your run it through winrm outside of an established session. But I really don't have enough winfoo to see what could cause that in your script. Someone with better skills might have a clue.

Comment: @Zeitounator, you were 100% correct! When I was testing the PowerShell script manually, I logged into the server using my personal account to trigger it. The playbook is using a different windows user to trigger the script and when I tried to trigger the script with that user (manually from the win 
server) it showed the credentials prompt window. Once that was fixed, managed to get the playbook to work.

Thanks for the help!